# Installing Simba ODBC Driver for Excel

Tags: google-bigquery

I downloaded the Simba ODBC driver for macOS and when I run the dmg it gives me the following and doesn't let me proceed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250425993?answerId=251004407022#251004407022) comment on the official Apple support page helped me to solve this problem.

Basically, you need to drag the .pkg file to the folder, I used the Downloads folder. Then use right click on the .pkg file in your Downloads folder and click Open and then Open again.